# mapping a many-to-one relationship causes a MappingException

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I'm having a problem with mapping a many-to-one relationship I've never encountered before.

Information:

- The exception I get when I try to generate my database scheme is:

  > [Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]
  >   Class Monkeyproof\Uploaderbundle\Entity\Folder is not a valid entity
  >   or mapped super class.
- A GroupPermission has one folder
- I'm using XML mapping
- Folder is a subclass of *Entity*, which is correctly mapped as it worked correctly before I've added the new relation.

Here are my mapping files:

GroupPermission.orm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
                  http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">

    <entity name="Monkeyproof\UploaderBundle\Entity\GroupPermission">

        <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
            <generator strategy="AUTO"/>
        </id>

        <field name="permissionType" type="integer" nullable="false" />

        <many-to-one target-entity="Folder" field="folder" />
    </entity>

</doctrine-mapping>
```

Folder.orm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">

<entity name="Monkeyproof\UploaderBundle\Entity\Folder"
        repository-class="Monkeyproof\UploaderBundle\Repository\FolderRepository">

    <one-to-many target-entity="Entry" mapped-by="parentFolder" field="content">
        <cascade>
            <cascade-persist/>
            <cascade-remove/>
        </cascade>
    </one-to-many>
</entity>
```

In my GroupPermission entity:

```
/**
 * @var \Monkeyproof\UploaderBundle\Entity\Folder
 */
protected $folder;
```

Comment: Do you where the exception is thrown (in which file?) there are a few possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

```
Class Monkeyproof\Uploaderbundle\Entity\Folder is not a valid entity or mapped super class.
```

1) Make sure Monkeyproof\Uploaderbundle\Entity\Folder is an entity i.e.

```
// Monkeyproof\Uploaderbundle\Entity\Folder
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
 class Folder {..}
```

2) This unlikely since you mentioned that it once worked but this error may be caused when you are not using auto-mapping and using explicit em. Do you have the below configuration?

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                mappings:
                    MonkeyproofUploaderBundle: ~
```

3) Lastly, make sure cache is cleared, including apc if you are using it.